# Telegram Bot sendMessage not working on google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, bots, telegram

```
var token="yourtoken";
var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/tokenappscript/exec";

function getMe() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/getMe");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function getUpdates() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/getUpdates");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendMessage(id, text) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" +  id + "&text=" + text);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Ciao" + JSON.stringify(e));
}

function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "Telegram Bot Update", JSON.stringify(contents,null,4));
  var text = contents.message.text;
  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  var name = contents.message.from.fist.name + " " + contents.message.from.last_name;
  sendMessage(id, "Hi " + name);
}
```

I'll trying for now only send a message from the bot in response to my hi. But when i type hi nothing happened, the bot not responding with hi. I see my message when i type and get the log in my email.

Comment: What is the response you got from telegram server?

Comment: i take only the take in my email the update response in json format every time i type something in telegram bot.